# S3 Bucket policy access denied

Tags: amazon-s3, policy, bucket

I am trying to setup AWS S3 policy for a specific user.It works find when i attach a policy to a user but my bucket policy access denied. Started with specific actions but in the following it is wide open. Here is my policy.Appreciate, if you can point out on what am i missing here.

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1540550791287",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1540550707671",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testabc1234abc",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<accountid>:user/test1"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1540550788846",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testabc1234abc/*",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<accountid>:user/test1"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you wish to grant access for a specific user, the best method is to attach the permissions to the IAM User directly. This way, the Bucket Policy does not grow too complex (especially if you start doing similar for other users). Is there a reason why you wish to use a Bucket Policy?

Comment: Currently, It is working as expected with attaching a policy to the user and agree with your comments that it will be difficult to manage to add many principles at bucket level. Although it is not user-specific, I had a hard time making the bucket policy working unless making it as public(means making principle as *). Not sure what is not right here?